# Looking for some background on closed linear span

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I'm starting a book on generalized analytic continuation and the phrase 'closed linear span', which I haven't encountered, has popped up several times in the introduction. The first context was: for each $n\in \mathbb{N}^+$, let $S= \{z_{n,1},\ldots, z_{n,N(n)}\}$ be a finite set of points in $\mathbb{D}_e=\{z \,:\, 1\leq |z|\leq \infty\}$, and define
$$
R_n := \bigvee \left\{ \frac{1}{z-z_{n,j}}: 1\leq j \leq N(n)\right\};
$$here it claims $\bigvee$ is the closed linear span, which is where my question begins.

My intuition says it is similar to the normal concept of span in a vector space. At some point or another I've taken courses in linear algebra, complex analysis, and measure theory- if those are relevant- but I haven't taken any functional analysis. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Closed linear span means the (topological) closure of the linear span of a set

Comment: And here that would take place in the space of continuous functions over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: I doubt it's in the space of continuous functions $\Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$, because the map $z\mapsto \dfrac{1}{z-z_{n,j}}$ is not even defined at $z_{n,j}$, nor can it be extended to a continuous map on $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Right, duh. I wonder where then...

Comment: I myself have only taken a first course in complex analysis, so I'm not too sure, but probably the space of meromorphic functions on $\Bbb{C}$, equipped with a suitable topology?

Comment: here it is just the set of the rational functions of the given type (in the sense that if a point repeats then you allow higher poles at the point); in general, one uses the standard topology for analytic (meromorphic) functions, namely local uniform convergence which is Frechet (metrizable, locally convex etc - taking an exhaustive countable set of compacts and the sup norm there divided by some power of two and adding them) - and infinity corresponds to constants and then infinity repeated once to $z$

Comment: say the set is $2,3,3,\infty, \infty$ then the space has dimension $5$ and consists of functions that are $a/(z-2)+b/(z-3)+c/(z-3)^2+d+ez$